# EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals relies on equals implementation of each field

Tags: java, apache-commons

I wanted to use reflectionEquals for some of my tests but found that it only works when the classes of all non null fields implements equals. This is not the case for some of my fields. I thought about using a subclass with that overrides equals and uses explicitly uses reflectionEquals on the field that does not implement equals (headers). This works but is messy and wanted to check if there's a better way. The reason identity equals does not work in my tests is I'm using gson to marshall objects to a database. Here's my subclass solution:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TrackingEvent other = (TrackingEvent) obj;
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this.getHeaders(), other.getHeaders()) && 
                EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other, new String[] {"headers"});
    }
```

Comment: The simplest solution to this is to write a traditional `equals` implementation by hand operating on the fields you want to operate on.

Comment: Yes, of course if I relied on equals in production code I would implement it, but I don't and want a zero maintenance equals for test code.